# AngularJS property change event/listener on list<model>

Tags: angularjs

there. I need an watcher or an event which will be fired when a property on the model (Details), which is keept in a list (products), changes.

View:

```
<tr class="data-row" data-ng-repeat="c in c.products">
{{c.name}} <-- if c.name changes fire an event
{{c.expire}} <-- if c.expirechanges fire an event
{{[...]}} <-- c contains many properties
```

ViewModel

```
c.setDirtyFlag()
{
    c.dirty=true;
}
```

Is there an angularjs solution for this problem? greetings

@Shomz I tried the watch with the following code. But when the property c.expires will be changed in the input field the watch will not be raised.

```
    $scope.$watch("c.products.expire", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        log.debug(newValue);
    });
```

EDIT: To be more specific:
The product list will be generated during runtime. Also the user can add and remove items. This "temporary" added objects should also be watched.

Comment: Have you tried [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)ing for changes?

Comment: Angular has a 'dirty' attribute on the form... see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: Setting a property like c.dirty=true; on property changed was only an example. I need to run custom code when a property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a $watch on each item in the $scope.products array variable and perform event handling that way.

```
_.each(products, function(product) {
    $scope.$watch(function() { return product; }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal.name != oldVal.name || newVal.expire != oldVal.expire || ...) {
            //do event work
            product._isDirty = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you wrap this in a form, you can check the $dirty variable for that form to see if any.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. When I add an item - a product I have to add it also to the $scope.$watch?

Comment: @Briefkasten Yeah, but be careful. I may have misunderstood the scenario. If you're constantly managing that array, you would not watch to be declaring watches over and over again. What, more specifically, are you trying to do?

Comment: @Briefkasten As part of the 2 way binding, if you just re-assign the new array of objects to the $scope.products variable, the list in the view will automatically update. If that's all you're looking for, you won't need a watch.

Comment: I need to execute some webapi calls when a specific property changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing me into the right direction @wbeange. This is my current solution. The $watchlist didn't worked as I expected so I used the "old" $watch.

```
$scope.$watch("c.products",
               function (newValue, oldValue) {
                   //first initialising of list
                   if (typeof newValue != 'undefined' && c.products.length > 0) {

                       if (newValue != oldValue && oldValue!=null) {

                           for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
                               if (newValue[i].expire!= oldValue[i].expire
                                   || newValue[i].otherprop != oldValue[i].otherprop)
                               {
                                   //todo
                               }
                           }

                       }
                   }
               },
               true // Object equality (not just reference).
           );
```